TARGET attribute in hyperlink in a window open bye window.open () function
When I put the TARGET="info" attribute in different <A> tags, all the targeted pages open in the same tab.
But if I do the same thing in a page that was itself created by a call to window.open(...), then each hyperlink will open a new tab, as if the TARGET attribute was ignored.
I have this behavior on Chrome and Firefox.
My first question is: what is the reason, if there is one?
Second: is there a way to force opening on the same tab?

Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve].
